# grep with pattern (i.e., search for mutliple strings/searches/options) -- file type can't be specified?

Tags: grep

I would like to do a recursive grep and search for multiple strings/options at the first time (I think this might be called pattern? not sure).

Semantically, I want so search for "foo | bar". There are various options. Among others: `grep -- "foo\|bar" *.txt` does the job.

I cannot use that command though since I didn't figure out how to tell it to search recursively. I.e., the '-r' attribute doesn't work. **Q1: Any idea?**

Anyway, I find the following option more convenient anyway:

`grep -r -f patternfile *` because it allows me to place my matches ("foo" and "bar" and any other) into a file (here called patternfile), one per line. If one searches for many expressions, this is clearly more convenient and readable.

However this has its disadvantages as well! It seems like I have to specify "*" here for what is being searched. But of course I want to restrict it, for example to text files, *.txt. But that doesn't work... **Q2: How to use this command with *.txt at the end? (And why doesn't it accept that in the first place?)**

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try:

```
grep -r --include="*.txt" "foo\|bar" .
```

If your `grep` does not support the `--include` option, here is an alternative:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 grep "foo\|bar"
```